# How to write my own Sleep function using just time.After?

Tags: time, go, sleep, channel

I'm trying to write my own sleep function equivalent to `time.Sleep` using `time.After` in Go.

Here's the code. First attempt:

```
func Sleep(x int) {
  msg := make(chan int)
  msg := <- time.After(time.Second * x)
}
```

Second attempt:

```
func Sleep(x int) {
 time.After(time.Second * x)
}
```

Both return errors, can someone explain to me how to write a sleep function equivalent to `time.Sleep` using `time.After` and if possible when do I use channel?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582143/golang-using-timeouts-with-channels as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466320/is-there-a-way-to-do-repetitive-tasks-at-intervals-in-golang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) returns you a channel. And a value will be send on the channel after the specified duration.

So just receive a value from the returned channel, and the receive will block until the value is sent:

```
func Sleep(x int) {
    <-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(x))
}
```

**Your errors:**

In your first example:

```
msg := <- time.After(time.Second * x)
```

`msg` is already declared, and so the [Short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) `:=` cannot be used. Also the recieved value will be of type [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), so you can't even assign it to `msg`.

In your second example you need a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) as `x` is of type `int` and `time.Second` is of type [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration), and `time.After()` expects a value of type `time.Duration`.

Comment: Thank you so much icza, you safe me again. I have so much questions on golang.

Comment: I don't understand this part **<-time.After(time.Second * time.Duration(x))** is it receiving ?

Comment: @airsoftFreak `time.After()` returns a channel. And the `<-` is the [receive operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) applied on the return value of `time.After()`.

Comment: Can someone explain how to use the Sleep(x int) function above?

```go Sleep(10)``` with a print statement after executes immediately so I know this isn't working for me.

Comment: @Shawn 3 years later, here's your answer :P - because you used `go` in front of `Sleep`, it executed the sleep in a goroutine (in the background) and executed the print straight after. If you remove the `go` it should work just fine.