# select ignored slow case?

Tags: go, channel

I'm using such a `select` on multiple cases:

```
for {
    select {
    case data:= <- highFreqChan:
        // do something:
    case <- time.After(time.Second * 5):
        // send some heartbeat like data...
    }
}
```

I find that, if `highFreqChan` got huge data, the heartbeat case will not enter, and when stop sending data to `highFreqChan`, the heartbeat case alive again, how to make it always enter the heartbeat case while the `highFreqChan` still working?

Comment: You can add the heartbeat to separate goroutine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Sleep function based on time.After](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937883/writing-sleep-function-based-on-time-after/32937957#32937957).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running `time.After` as part of the select condition, which means it's evaluated at the time the select is reached... which means that it will expire 5 seconds *after* the select is reached. So you will only enter that case if `highFreqChan` doesn't have any data for 5 seconds straight.

If you want to do something *every* 5 seconds, use a [time.Ticker](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker) instead, like so:

```
heartbeat := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
defer heartbeat.Stop()
for {
    select {
    case data:= <- highFreqChan:
        // do something:
    case <- heartbeat.C:
        // send some heartbeat like data...
    }
}
```